# How to transform a flat form-specific data-structure into a nested one?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, properties, form-data, object-destructuring

I have a requirement where one needs to inflate a form-specific flat data-structure. Before sending the user entered values, I need to build a data-structure according to what the server's API does expect.

Say I have following key-value pairs from a user's input

```
{
  state: "California",
  city: "New York",
  full_name: "rererer",
  email: "eee@gg.com",
  dob: "1/1/2014",
  pincode: "222222",
  gender: "male",
}
```

The data API does require a nested object where

1. an `Address` will include `state`, `city` and `full_name`
2. and a `Profile` has to feature `email`, `dob`, `pincode` and `gender`.

How does one convert the above key-value pairs into following nested data-structure?

```
{
  Address: {
    state: "California",
    city: "New York",
    full_name: "rererer",
  },
  Profile: {
    email: "eee@gg.com",
    dob: "1/1/2014",
    pincode: "222222",
    gender: "male",
  },
}
```

Comment: _"the server will define the object name and what field to include in that object in the initial JSON"_ - you have not shown us what that actually looks like - but it sounds like you simply need to _iterate_ over that, and then pick the corresponding properties out of your data object ...?

Comment: @Nabajyoti ... Regarding both the answers, are there any questions left?

Comment: I am evaluating which is a viable solution. After that will upvote the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example is that you can store the json in a variable as **X** wherein you can create 2 object **Address** and **Profile** then put the required fields from the X variable to its respective objects and later merge that object together.

Example:

```
var jsonObj = {
  state: "California",
  city: "New York",
  full_name: "rererer",
  email: "eee@gg.com",
  dob: "1/1/2014",
  pincode: "222222",
  gender: "male"
};

var address = new Object();
var profile = new Object();
var combinedObj = new Object();

address.state = jsonObj.state 
address.city = jsonObj.city 
address.full_name = jsonObj.full_name 

profile.email = jsonObj.email
profile.dob = jsonObj.dob
profile.pincode = jsonObj.pincode
profile.gender = jsonObj.gender

combinedObj.Address = address
combinedObj.Profile = profile

console.log(combinedObj);
```

you can automate this code

Comment: There is not such a thing like a JSON-object. JSON is a data exchange format which represents JSON compatible data as string value/s. An object which is compatible to JSON can be always referred to as data-structure. Do not name it json-object / `jsonObj`.

Answer (score 0):

In short, such an object could be created by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) the original data before the final re/assembling takes place where one would utilize the [object literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#description) together with e.g. [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions) and a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) ...

```js
const sourceData = {
  state: "California",
  city: "New York",
  full_name: "rererer",
  email: "eee@gg.com",
  dob: "1/1/2014",
  pincode: "222222",
  gender: "male",
};

// 1) destructuring.
const {
  state, city, full_name, email, dob, pincode, gender
} =
  sourceData;

// 2) re/assembling (object literal syntax).
const targetData = {
  Address: {
    // shorthand property names.
    state, city, full_name,
  },
  Profile: {
    // a template literal and shorthand property names.
    email: `[${ email }](mailto:${ email })`, dob, pincode, gender,
  },
};
console.log({ sourceData, targetData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

A generic approach for this kind of challenge almost always would utilize the [`FormData` Web-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) where one would [create the raw data-object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) from the [form-data's `entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries). The finally to be sent payload data then can be assembled easily from the before retrieved and [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) raw data by utilizing the [object literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#description) together with e.g. [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions) and a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) ...

```js
function handleProfileAndAddressDataSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  const { currentTarget: elmForm } = evt;
  const { action: serviceURL, method: apiMethod } = elmForm;

  const formData = new FormData(elmForm);
  const {
    // - destructured and partially renamed
    //   from the before created raw data object.
    state, location: city, full_name,
    email, dob, pincode, gender,
  } =
    // - creating the raw data object
    //   from the form-data's entries.
    Object.fromEntries([...formData.entries()]);

  const payload = {
    // - assambling the final payload object / object literal syntax.
    Address: {
      // shorthand property names.
      state, city, full_name,
    },
    Profile: {    
      // a template literal and shorthand property names.
      email: `[${ email }](mailto:${ email })`, dob, pincode, gender,
    },
  };

  console.log({
    elmForm, formEntries: [...formData.entries()], rawData: {
      email, dob, gender, pincode, full_name, location: city, state,
    },
    payload, apiMethod, serviceURL,
  });
  console.log(
    `Payload data will be send via "${ apiMethod.toUpperCase() }" to "${ serviceURL }"`
  );
}
document
  .forms[0]
  .addEventListener('submit', handleProfileAndAddressDataSubmit);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
fieldset  { margin: 0 4px 8px; padding: 8px; }
fieldset > label, label > span:first-child { display: block; margin: 0 0 4px 0; }
[type="submit"] { margin: 8px 16px; }
form { width: 35% ;}
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 64%; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<form method="post" action="./api/service/path">
  <datalist id="gender-list">
    <option>non binary</option>
    <option>female</option>
    <option>male</option>
  </datalist>

  <datalist id="federal-states">
    <option>Alabama</option>
    <option>California</option>
    <option>Delaware</option>
    <option>Florida</option>
    <option>Georgia</option>
    <option>Hawaii</option>
    <option>Idaho</option>
  </datalist>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Profile</legend>

    <label>
      <span>Email Address</span>
      <input type="email" required name="email" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Date Of Birth</span>
      <input type="date" required name="dob" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Gender</span>
      <input type="text" list="gender-list" required name="gender" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Pin Code</span>
      <input type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="\d{6}" required value="000000" name="pincode" />
    </label>

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Address</legend>

    <label>
      <span>Full Name</span>
      <input type="text" required name="full_name" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>City / Location</span>
      <input type="text" required name="location" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>State</span>
      <input type="text" list="federal-states" required name="state" />
    </label>
  </fieldset>

  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```